# Word for specific people

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for specific people with whom we **just interact** in day to day life?

They aren't friends, colleagues, relatives or customers etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the word **Acquaintance**.

*As per Oxford Dictionary* it means

**1**.Slight knowledge of or friendship with someone.

**Example**: ‘I renewed my acquaintance with Herbert’

**2. A person one knows slightly, but who is not a close friend.**

**Example**: ‘a wide circle of friends and acquaintances’

Answer (score 0):

If by "interaction in day to day life" you mean those in a workplace or school, one word is **peer** shown as noun 2 in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peer).

> A person of the same age, status, or ability as another specified
>   person.

Another similar word is **contemporary** shown as noun 1 in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contemporary).

> A person or thing living or existing at the same time as another.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing something "*in-between*" an "**acquaintance**" and a "**stranger**", but you do also specify "**interact**". The ideas "*fleeting* or *random*" seem to be suggested as well.

> As a single word you could use - "**interactant**" - but it is cold,
>   almost inhuman, and probably does not convey the desired meaning.
>
> Another word might be - "**associate**" - but it would probably
>   require a modifier like "random". It usually suggests someone "already
>   known" or known better than you imply.
>
> I think the single word "**acquaintance**", which has already given as
>   an answer, would probably be the best choice. Here again, it can
>   suggest someone "already known".
>
> You might use the single word "**stranger**", but it does carry the
>   idea of never having met before.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/interactant

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquaintance

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stranger